# My Android opengl app crashes after sleeping

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-2.2-froyo

I know this is something i should have learned before switching to opengl es 1.0 from software drawing, but I've been unable to find any information on the subject...

My opengl app crashes after going to sleep if nothing is touched for a while... I'm wondering if it's because i'm not unloading textures or vertex/colour/texture/index buffers before it goes to sleep... I'm really unsure on how to do this or even if it would help... could someone direct me to or tell me a quick guide to the rules of what has to be reloaded, destroyed and so on? I'm really confused by all this...

I dunno if it's helpful, but my main class extends GLSurfaceView and implements "Renderer", which loads all the textures and buffer objects in onScreenCreated and fixes the screen scaling on onSurfaceChanged. In the main activity (which is where the main class is linked in) overides onResume and onPause calling the onResume and onPause openGL surface commands...

Any clue to what might be wrong would be very helpful... My game engine is halfway coded but I'm worried that a glitch like this will just halt my current and future projects.

I'm using Froyo (android 2.2) and openGL ES 1.0.

error print out from logcat:

> 10-24 03:13:41.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9888): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 26
>
> 10-24 03:13:41.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9888): java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started.
>
> 10-24 03:13:41.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9888):     at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1322)
>
> 10-24 03:13:41.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9888):     at or.gl.m5.Screen.onSurfaceCreated(Screen.java:161)
>
> 10-24 03:13:41.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9888):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1317)
>
> 10-24 03:13:41.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9888):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1116)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing a stack trace or what kind of exception it throws out it is kind of hard to say something. But anyway I'm throwing a wild guess that it crashes because you have to reload textures after your activity is resumed. The textures you have previously created become invalid once your view goes to background.

Comment: I'd love tp show some debug crash reports, but everytime I try to debug my opengl work it just shows a black screen and I don't get any useful information... Any pointers on that would be great... I'm using eclipse as my compiler and I test through my device instead of the emulator. (if that helps)
Where should the textures be reloaded? I load them in "onCreateSurface"... is this incorrect? Do I have to unload them before reloading them? Sorry for all the questions to your reply, I just really don't know what I should be doing.

Comment: See the logs using the android logcat(either from inside eclipse ide or from the console). Check the messages with level ERROR otherwise it will be to crowded. When your application crashes it should printout a stack trace where it happened.

Comment: And about the textures, you don't need to unload them. You just need to reload them `onResume`.

Comment: I added the logcat error print out that pops up when the app crashes from waking to the question post... Does it still just look like texture loading problems? Just to clarify: the textures are  reloaded in "onSurfaceCreated", not an overwrite of onResume, right?

Comment: I just fixed it... turns out it wasn't the textures at all, but it was because I placed the gameThread starting point in onSurfacecreated... Thanks SO much for telling me how logCat works, it really helped alot :D